# How to create a 3d axes object

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-3d

I'm trying to make a three-dimensional plot, but I can't create the 3D Axes.

When I try, it gives me the an error stating "ValueError: Unknown projection '3d'".

Here's how I've tried to create the Axes object

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

plt.show()
```

How do I create a 3D Axes object in matplotlib?

Comment: You have to import 3d axes like `from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D`

Answer (score 7):

In order to create a 3D Axes, you need to import the `mplot3d` toolkit:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

plt.show()
```

There are several 3D examples in the gallery:
http://matplotlib.org/examples/mplot3d

Answer (score 0):

From the [Matplotlib documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/figure_api.html), "Valid values for projection are: [‘aitoff’, ‘hammer’, ‘lambert’, ‘mollweide’, ‘polar’, ‘rectilinear’]".

You are providing an invalid keyword argument to the `add_subplot()` method. It looks like you are trying to create a 3D plot in Cartesian coordinates. The projection keyword is not needed to make such a plot.

Comment: This isn't wrong, but `3D` can be a valid projection if the right toolkits are imported. See my answer.